# Can anyone explain this behavior? (Setting a lat/long to public double auto properties)

Tags: c#, debugging, double, monodevelop, latitude-longitude

I think the screenshot explains it best...

[image]

However, the issue is, I'm passing in a lat/long as two doubles to this GeoCoord object. The object has two public properties Latitude and Longitude.

Doing...

```
Latitude = lat;
```

The debugger shows two very different things for Latitude and lat afterward.

I'm using MonoDevelop and I haven't been able to replicate the issue in Visual Studio or in a test console project using MonoDevelop.

It seems like the values are getting represented well enough internally, it just makes debugging pretty hard when the values it shows for Latitude and Longitude seem to be almost random.

Comment: First step is to rule out a debugger error.  Have you tried printing out the values to the Console?

Comment: Yes, Console prints it properly.

Comment: Then the issue is likely just a bug in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks. It's unfortunate though. Perhaps I'll switch it to storing lat/long as decimal types then so I can actually get useful information from the debugger.

Comment: It looks like it might be a bug in returning double values from method invocations (in this case, property getters) in the debugger. If you could inspect the backing field, it would probably be correct.

Comment: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1949